# Change the view based on screen size

Tags: angularjs

I am aware of a similar question being asked before:

[Change the templateUrl of directive based on screen resolution AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25620368/change-the-templateurl-of-directive-based-on-screen-resolution-angularjs)

This was first asked over a year ago and since then AngularJS got changed a bit. I am curious to find out if there are any other ways to achieve something similar as I haven't found many information about templateUrl swapping, so maybe I am barking up the wrong tree here.

I have a single page app without any routes.

html:

```
<body ng-app="App">
  // lots of html same for both desktop/mobile
  <my-dir></my-dir>
  // even more here
</body>
```

template 1:

```
<p>Mobile</p>
```

template 2:

```
<p>Desktop</p>
```

I would like to render **template 1** when the screen goes below 700px and **template 2** otherwise. The templates change just what is inside **my-dir directive**. For example Template 1 renders list and template 2 renders table.

Another requirement would be to make it responsive if possible(aka templates would change as you resize the window)

At the moment I can use the solution from the above questions but are there any other ways to do it?

Comment: Hava you considered using [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) ?

Comment: Yes there are two options we are looking at now - one is a template swapping second is a pure CSS. There might be a lot of changes to structure so I am checking if template/directive swapping is possible with out to much hacking

Answer (score 10):

In your controller:

```
$scope.includeDesktopTemplate = false;
$scope.includeMobileTemplate = false; 
var screenWidth = $window.innerWidth;

if (screenWidth < 700){
    $scope.includeMobileTemplate = true;
}else{
    $scope.includeDesktopTemplate = true;
}
```

html template:

```
<body ng-app="App">
    <p ng-if="includeMobileTemplate">Mobile</p>
    <p ng-if="includeDesktopTemplate">Desktop</p>
</body>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: it is working fine on load but I can get it working on live resizes without running digest cycle on angular. React version: http://plnkr.co/edit/PYOQ23X2Xu93CaJMcKij?p=preview

Comment: @Kocur4d, I am not sure but I don't think you can get it working without running digest cycle. One way to do that could be using `$watch`, but that does run digest anyway.

Comment: I mean not to start it my self with $scope.$apply. I personally find the need of running $scope.$apply yourself as a bit of a hack(maybe it is just me), but in general i think you can alway redesign it to not to use it.

Answer (score 4):

You can add window resize and scroll event listener on `my-dir` directive:

```
angular.module("App").directive('myDir', ['$window', '$timeout', function($window, $timeout){

    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {},
        template:'<div>
            <p ng-if="showFirstTemplate">Mobile</p>
            <p ng-if="showSecondTemplate">Desktop</p>
            </div>',
        link: function(scope, element, attr){

            function checkTemplateVisible(event){

                 //use $timeout to make sure $apply called in a time manner
                 $timeout(function(){

                      //pageYoffset is equal to window scroll top position
                      if($window.pageYOffset > 700){
                          scope.showFirstTemplate = true;
                          scope.showSecondTemplate = false;
                      }else{
                          scope.showFirstTemplate = false;
                          scope.showSecondTemplate = true;
                      }
                 })

            })

            //scroll event make sure checkTemplateVisible called on browser scrolling
            $window.on('scroll', checkTemplateVisible)

            //resize event make sure checkTemplateVisible called on browser resizing
            $window.on('resize', checkTemplateVisible)
        }
    }


}])
```

Comment: ah I have been bit busy - i will test it this week