# Change the templateUrl of "more then one" with directives in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, window-resize

I've been looking for a way to change the templateUrl as the resize event.
I found the answer in the link:

[Change the templateUrl of directive based on screen resolution AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25620368/change-the-templateurl-of-directive-based-on-screen-resolution-angularjs)

Posted by mr. "Dfsq". It worked well until when I needed to do the same process in two different templatesUrls the same time. Did not work.
When I delete a directive the other goes to work.

Any idea where I am wrong.

Plunker follows.
[Plunker Example Here!](http://plnkr.co/edit/gNsWfWimwLyGfKlZE2yv?p=preview)

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
});

angular.module('plunker')
  .directive('browseContent', function($window) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div ng-include="templateUrl"></div>',
        link: function(scope) {
            
            $window.onresize = function() {
                changeTemplate();
                scope.$apply();
            };
            changeTemplate();
            
            function changeTemplate() {
                var screenWidth = $window.innerWidth;
                if (screenWidth < 768) {
                    scope.templateUrl = 'browse-content-mobile.html';
                } else if (screenWidth >= 768) {
                    scope.templateUrl = 'browse-content.html';
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
  .directive('segundoContent', function($window) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div ng-include="templateUrl2"></div>',
        link: function(scope) {
            
            $window.onresize = function() {
                changeTemplate2();
                scope.$apply();
            };
            changeTemplate2();
            
            function changeTemplate2() {
                var screenWidth = $window.innerWidth;
                if (screenWidth < 768) {
                    scope.templateUrl2 = 'segundoContent.html';
                } else if (screenWidth >= 768) {
                    scope.templateUrl2 = 'segundoContent-mobile.html';
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>
        document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.22/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.22"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <browse-content></browse-content>
    <segundo-content></segundo-content>
</body>

</html>
```

I appreciate the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you are using `onresize` method which will potentially register a single event on resize of window, so when you are having 2nd directive in DOM it registering latest function on resize.

Ideally you should be using `resize` with `handler` functoin, so that multiple event will get register at the same time.

**browseContent Directive**

```
var w = angular.element($window);
w.on('resize', function(e) {
    changeTemplate();
    scope.$apply();
});
```

**segundoContent Directive**

```
var w = angular.element($window)
w.on('resize', function() {
    changeTemplate2();
    scope.$apply();
});
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/cZ7p1dXWKfubJJhVZ8mQ?p=preview)

---

More convenient way would be just use a single directive and pass templateUrl function / templateUrl's itself to it, so that directive will become more generic & you would not need to create a two directive at a time.

**HTML**

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <browse-content templates="htmls"></browse-content>
    <browse-content templates="segundo"></segundo-content>
</body>
```

**Code**

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.htmls = ['browse-content-mobile.html', 'browse-content.html'];
  $scope.segundo = ['segundoContent.html', 'segundoContent-mobile.html'];
});

angular.module('plunker')
  .directive('browseContent', function($window) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      template: '<div ng-include="templateUrl"></div>',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var w = angular.element($window);
        w.on('resize', function(e) {
          changeTemplate();
          scope.$apply();
        });
        var templates = scope.$eval(attrs.templates);
        console.log(templates)
        changeTemplate();

        function changeTemplate() {
          var screenWidth = $window.innerWidth;
          if (screenWidth < 768) {
            scope.templateUrl = templates[0];
          } else if (screenWidth >= 768) {
            scope.templateUrl = templates[1];
          }
        }
      }
    }
});
```

[**Better Approach**](http://plnkr.co/edit/UegK1simJMS3hTrE7DLI?p=preview)

---

Comment: Added the methods of the directives. Both stopped working.
What would be the place to add them?
Thank you for your help. sr. Pankaj

Comment: @user3403205 please look at the updated code & plunkr as well, Thanks :)

Comment: Amazing. sr. Pankaj.
Thank you very much.

Comment: @user3403205 Use the second approach by which you can use it as a generic directive, Thanks :)