# How to implement Adaptive web design in one application

Tags: angular

Is there a way to have 2 templates in one component? I meant for example the website that I am building is not responsive web design. So, there are 2 different views, desktop and mobile views. I want to use the same application for both. How can I switch between two templates (one for desktop view and one for mobile view) in a component based on user’s device? Is that possible?

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, can you check to see if this answers your question?  Otherwise may need some clarification: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25620368/change-the-templateurl-of-directive-based-on-screen-resolution-angularjs

Answer (score 0):

First, you will have to detect screen size on initialization and set a special flag to know what device the app is currently run on.

```
initializeRWD() {
    if (screen.width < 1080) {
        this.isSmallScreen = true;
    } else {
        this.isSmallScreen = false;
    }
}
```

Next, I would put a `<div class="desktop">` and `<div class="mobile">` in your template and depending on the screensize show either of them, for example:

```
<div class="desktop"> *ngIf="!isSmallScreen">
    <!-- desktop code here -->
</div>

<div class="mobile" *ngIf="isSmallScreen">
<!-- mobile code here -->
</div>`
```